# How can I render partial element/html/layout checking with a contoller/action url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If the url is http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_in then it will not call the partial

```
<%= render :partial => "/posts/rightsidediv" %>
```

else it will call that partial

```
<%= render :partial => "/posts/rightsidediv" %>
```

How can i check that url or controller/action ?

Comment: Are you using a gem for authentication? If so, what gem are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `params` there are `:controller` and `:action` so you can use them to limit the render call like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "posts/your_partial" unless params[:controller == "users"] && params[:action] == "sign_up" %>
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Can you post code with if else, if-else looks easier to me than unless.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
<%= render(:partial => "/posts/rightsidediv") unless current_page?(:controller => 'users', :action => 'sign_in') %>
```

Comment: Can you post code with if else, if-else looks easier to me than unless.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? unless is just the exact opposite of "if" and keeps your code clean. Are you wanting to render something else if it is that current page?

Comment: If it's sign_in page then it won't render that partial, the partial is set in application.html.erb for the whole project.

Comment: Then what I posted is exactly what you are needing. It is concise, to the point, and reads like normal human language more than an if else where you would have nothing running in the if anyways.

The if would look like:
`<% if current_page?(:controller => "users", :action => "sign_in") %>
    #nothing at all would be here... not even this comment
<% else %>
    <%= render :partial => "/posts/rightsidediv" %>
<% end %>`

Which takes up more than one line, is less legible, and also utilizes an if that never gets used.